# Serializing Protobuf Object and Sending with ØMQ/ZMQ

Tags: c#, c++, zeromq, protobuf-net

I have a protobuf object that I am sending from a C# application (using clrZmq) to a C++ service (using the zmq C++ bindings) on a local machine (for testing). I attempt to send my object from C# using the following

```
Taurus.Odds odds = Util.GetFakeOdds();
using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
using (var socket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REQ))
{
    byte[] buffer = null;
    socket.Connect(TARGET); // TARGET = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6500"

    Taurus.FeedMux mux = new Taurus.FeedMux();
    mux.type = Taurus.FeedMux.Type.ODDS;
    mux.odds = odds;

    SendStatus status = socket.Send(mux.ToByteArray());
    if (status == SendStatus.Sent)
    {
        int i;
        byte[] arr = socket.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None, out i);
        Taurus.Bet bet = buffer.ToObject<Taurus.Bet>();
    }
...
}
```

Where I am serializing to my `Taurus.Odds` object to `byte[]` via the extension method

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(this object o)
{
     if(o == null)
          return null;
     BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         bf.Serialize(ms, o);
         return ms.ToArray();
     }
}
```

I see in my C++ application that the code receives the message, but the C++ ZMQ classes fail to de-serialize it correctly. I have some Java code that send to the C++ code in the same way without issue. My question is, am I sending my object via ZMQ correctly in the above and if not what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using the text-based debugging format available in protobuf? (not sure if it is in C# version but it is the the google developed ones)

Comment: How could I use this format to help me? The serialization is working as I expect and creating the `byte` array correctly. I wonder if there is something obvious I am missing?

Comment: So you can visually inspect that the formatted message produced by the Java version and the C# version are the same. Or have you already checked that they are byte for byte the same?

Comment: Good shout, I don't have direct access to be able to debug the Java directly. I can browse the code base and I seem to be doing the same thing, but you are right. I will ask my co-working to check this for me. Thanks for your time, I will get back to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your error:

> I am serializing to my `Taurus.Odds` object to `byte[]` via the extension method
>
> ```
> ...
> BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
> ...
> ```

You seem to be unaware of what [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) is. It is **in no way related to ProtoBuf**. The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) say the following:

> Serializes and deserializes an object, or an entire graph of connected objects, **in binary format**.

This *binary format* is a .NET-specific *implementation detail*. And it's *very* rigid at that, with poor versioning support. It was mainly used in the .NET remoting days, and it's generally considered a bad idea to use it today, as there are *much better* serializers around.

As you can see, there's no way your C++ app could be able to read that, as it's not in protobuf format.

So throw this method away and replace it with some proper protobuf serializing code, as explained [in the protobuf-net docs](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted). You'll need to add `[ProtoContract]` and `[ProtoMember]` attributes in your objects. Then you could write something like:

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray<T>(this T o)
{
     if (o == null)
          return null;

     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(ms, o);
         return ms.ToArray();
     }
}
```